# How can I change what group and sub-group a DirectShow push source filter appears in?

Tags: c#, directx, directshow, video-codecs

I am using the code to create a C# DirectShow push source filter from the following open source article, that builds a filter called **VirtualCam**:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/437617/DirectShow-Virtual-Video-Capture-Source-Filter-in

The **GraphEdit** utility can find it and shows it in the **Video Capture Sources** group with the name **CSharp Virtual Camera**, and I can build a filter graph with it and *it works fine*.  Skype can find it too.  However, all the other software I want to use it with can't find it because it does not show up in a device enumeration call when using **VideoInputSource** as the main group.  I believe this is the class ID for that group:

```
/// <summary> CLSID_VideoInputDeviceCategory, video capture category </summary>
public static readonly Guid VideoInputDevice = new Guid(0x860BB310, 0x5D01, 0x11d0, 0xBD, 0x3B, 0x00, 0xA0, 0xC9, 0x11, 0xCE, 0x86);
```

I got that class ID from an open source utility that scans for video input devices.  It's one of the apps that can't find the **VirtualCam** filter either.  These apps can only find devices like my web cam (in other words, VirtualCam does *not* show up in the available device list).

What do I need to do to the **VirtualCam** source code so that it declares/registers itself as a video input device and will show up in a device enumeration scan in the **VideoInputDevice** category so most software can see it and use it?

**UPDATE**: Upon closer inspection in **GraphEdit** the main difference I see between the **VirtualCam** filter that can't be found by most apps and the video capture devices that *can* be found is that the **VirtualCam** filter *does not have any pins defined*, while the other video capture devices do.  If this is the problem, how should I define a pin properly that will allow **VirtualCam** to be discovered and will work properly to service the declared interface?

Comment: For what Application do you want it to show up. Maybe this application uses MediaFoundation as Videobackend! Then DirectShow filters don't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no subgroup, and the group is refered to as "category". Filters are registered into categories. The category of your interest here is `CLSID_VideoInputDeviceCategory` also known as "Video Capture Sources".

From registration standpoint, the only issue I can think of is 32/64 bitness. Filters registered as 32-bit filters are not visible to 64-bit apps and vice versa. This might be tricky because your project is C# and you might have it built for `AnyCPU`, however in any event you can use 32- and 64-bit GraphEdit (or rather [GraphStudioNext](https://github.com/cplussharp/graph-studio-next)) to make sure your filter is in the list. Presence in the list of filters ensures that registration step was passed.

From there on it is up to implementation of the application to show or not show specific video source. Some applications show every registered source, other like Skype attempt to instantiate source and do some initial check. If they don't like the source, it is removed from the list of choices.

The implementation requirements for the video source are not well defined, but most applications expect to get a filter compatible with [`WDM Video Capture Filter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390974). Better applications accept video source if SDK [AmCap sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373424) can preview it, worse implementations have other assumptions.

In general the video source MUST implement `IBaseFilter` in the filter class, and  `IPin`, `IAMStreamConfig` interfaces in the pins. It SHOULD implement `IQualityControl` and `IKsPropertySet` in pins as well. It would also be good to implement `ISpecifyPropertyPages` as poor implementations also might expect it there (even if no pages are attached).

Comment: Thanks.  Do you know if there is a utility like SysInternals ProcMon that would show me all the DirectShow calls an app is making so I can see what it expects?

Comment: There is no such tool. You should check the calls you receive in your classes, filter and pins (including `QueryInterface`) and you will be able to guess at which point it goes off the track.

Comment: Thanks, will do.  My first target is implementing IPin since I just checked the VirtualCam code and it does not implement that interface as far as I can tell.  Your suggestion for 32/64 bit did help.  I managed to get the filter to show up with a previously unsuccessful app by re-compiling it as 64 bit (at that point of course 32-bit GraphEdit couldn't see it anymore).  However, still no luck with the main app I want to get VirtualCam filter working with.

Comment: `IBaseFilter`, `IPin` are the first interfaces to implement - without them the filter is not operational in any app; the typical problem is `IAMStreamConfig` as it is optional in general, but it is assumed to be present in video sources in particular. Then other apps might have other assumptions.

Comment: Thanks again.  If know of a reference or sample implementation of a push source filter with source code that implements a  WDM Video Capture Filter properly I'd like to know, commerical or otherwise.  I spent all day trying out at least 5 C++ push source filters, including the one found in the Windows 7 SDK DirectShow samples directory, and about 4 C# ones too.  None of them are being discovered by the client app I'm targeting, probably for the list of unimplemented interfaces you mentioned.  I'm hoping to avoid a lot of trial and error experimentation that don't have time for.

Comment: It is a hard question because it is specific to this "target application". If it sees [IP Video Source](http://alax.info/blog/1223) as virtual device, I will list the interfaces it implements, perhaps this could be of any help.

Comment: I tried IP Video Source by creating a new source named Ajax.Info.  However, I did not specify a HTTP enabled camera since I don't have one.  GraphEdit was able to see the filter in the DirectShow category and I could build a runnable graph with it, with a black screen as output of course.  Skype did not discover it.  Unfortunately neither did the main app I'm trying to target my efforts too.  Thanks anyways and for the detailed help you gave me already.